# Why isn't `attr.$observe` callback triggered when value is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written a validation directive `multiple-pattern` that takes several validation regular expressions:

```
link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
    if (!ctrl) return;

    let validators = [];
    attr.$observe('multiplePattern', function (patterns) {
        // doesn't get there after value change
        var parsed = scope.$eval(patterns);
```

but I don't understand why `$observe` callback isn't triggered when variable on controller `validationRegexps` is changed (ng-repeat's callback is triggered when `regexp` variable is changed):

```
$scope.regexp = '^\\S*$';
$scope.validationRegexps = {'nospaces': '^\\S*$', 'nofirstnumber': '^[A-Za-z]'};

setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.regexp = '[^abc]';
        $scope.validationRegexps = {'noabc': '[^abc]'};
    })
}, 5000);
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-pattern="regexp" multiple-pattern="validationRegexps"></div>
```

Comment: why don't you use `scope: { multiplePatterns: '=' }`?

Comment: in nutshell: attrs is string, you observe string changes, you pass string _validationRegexps_ this string not change, so, callback not triggered

Comment: @DanielA.White, because my directive doesn't create isolate scope.

Comment: @Grundy, how then the callback for `ng-repeat` is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

`$observe` does work same as that of `$watch`. But the difference between these two is `$watch` takes `string` value or `expression` & evaluates on each digest cycle, where as `$observe` takes `interpolated` expression like `{{validationRegexps}}`.

`attr.$observe` will only work when you have used `attribute` with interpolated content `{{}}`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-pattern="regexp" multiple-pattern="{{validationRegexps}}"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but why then I don't need to use interpolated expression for `ng-pattern` for the callback to be triggered?

Comment: @Maximus if you debug the `ng-pattern` directive code, you will come to know that. I will only run the `$observe` callback function once. on initial which will take value from the `scope` variable and will place to `regx` variable value, which will then used by [`ctrl.$validators.pattern`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L169)

Comment: Yeah, I've just done exactly that, please see my answer.

Comment: @Maximus you can't say that is special handling, it would fire a callback function first time only.. try to change value of `regexp` scope variable which you are passing from `ng-pattern`, the `$observe` function will not get fired..

Comment: that's the point, it will get fired, that's basically my question is what about

Answer (score 0):

I just checked source code and it seems that there is a special handling of `ng-pattern` value which allows correct working of `$observe` without specifying interpolation:

```
var ALIASED_ATTR = {
  'ngMinlength': 'minlength',
  'ngMaxlength': 'maxlength',
  'ngMin': 'min',
  'ngMax': 'max',
  'ngPattern': 'pattern'
};


forEach(ALIASED_ATTR, function(htmlAttr, ngAttr) {
  ngAttributeAliasDirectives[ngAttr] = function() {
    return {
      priority: 100,
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        //special case ngPattern when a literal regular expression value
        //is used as the expression (this way we don't have to watch anything).
        if (ngAttr === "ngPattern" && attr.ngPattern.charAt(0) == "/") {
          var match = attr.ngPattern.match(REGEX_STRING_REGEXP);
          if (match) {
            attr.$set("ngPattern", new RegExp(match[1], match[2]));
            return;
          }
        }

        scope.$watch(attr[ngAttr], function ngAttrAliasWatchAction(value) {
          // here the value is already interpolated
          attr.$set(ngAttr, value);
        });
      }
    };
  };
});
```

As opposed to not interpolated value for other use cases of `$observe`:

```
  $observe: function(key, fn) {
    var attrs = this,
        $$observers = (attrs.$$observers || (attrs.$$observers = createMap())),
        listeners = ($$observers[key] || ($$observers[key] = []));

    listeners.push(fn);
    $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
      if (!listeners.$$inter && attrs.hasOwnProperty(key) && !isUndefined(attrs[key])) {
        // not interpolated value is passed down here
        fn(attrs[key]);
      }
    });

    return function() {
      arrayRemove(listeners, fn);
    };
  }
```

Comment: I'd not suggest you edit API code..which code fix your one problem but it can lead to other consequences.

Comment: I don't edit it, I just listed it here to demonstrate why `$observer` works differently for `ng-repeat` and my custom directive